# Redirect URL using htacces without domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I bought a new server that has not a domain yet, so I access it by using

```
http://IP/~user/main.php
```

I already have a .htaccess but it doesn't work when I try to access, for instance:

```
http://IP/~user/page001-8-65
```

I have rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page001-(.+)-(.+)/$  page001.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
RewriteRule ^page001-(.+)-(.+)$   page001-$1-$2/
```

Everything works fine when the domain is set, but i would like to know if I can make it work without changing it too much.

Comment: Try poisoning your host file so that only you can access by the domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment. I wouldn't change my htaccess rules at all so that you don't break anything. You can just update the host file on only your computer so that only you can see it by using the domain name. That way everything will work as expected while you are testing.

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/configuring-domain-settings/accessing-your-web-site-before-dns-propagation-is-complete#Method-2.3A-Use-the-hosts-file

FYI, once you are done testing and you have updated DNS with your IP, don't forget to remove the entry in the host file as it's not needed any more.

Comment: Hi, do I have to put  [ IP/~user domain.com ] or [ IP domain.com ]  is enough?

Comment: use the examples in the host file. The syntax is IP domain.com. e.g. `111.111.111.111 yoursite.com`, also make sure you edit the host file by opening it in notepad as administrator so it will allow you to save it.